# Detect when iPhone connect to any paired car

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bluetooth

Hello I would like to ask you how can I know when the user get in the car **(When the IOS device conect to any paired car)** and when the user get out of the car **( When IOS device disconnect from any paired car )**.

I dicovered that it is possible by going to "**Reminders**" on my iPhone and setting a reminder then going to "**details**" and press "**Remind me at a location**" and then I have the option to select "**Getting on the car**" or "**getting out of the car**".

I would really apreciate if you can answer my question or give me a link to a tutorial I am using Xcode and Objective C.

Comment: What solution did you end up going with?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use CoreBluetooth for this as it's only meant for BLE communication.
AFAIK, getting in or out of the car is tied to CarPlay, so that's also unusable at this time. External Accessory Framework only works for MFi devices.

You don't really have any choices left, so consider using an iBeacon, it might be the best solution after all.

Z.

Edit: If it's a viable solution for you, check out the private BluetoothManager framework.

Comment: With iOS 13, Apple has introduced support for BR/EDR Bluetooth device into CoreBluetooth. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/ So maybe it's possibile to use Corebluetooth in order to accomplish the required task.

Answer (score -1):

I found the following document through Apple Developer regarding the use of bluetooth. Hope it helps.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html